# Map IP Address (NGINX running) in cloudflare

Tags: nginx, ip, subdomain, ip-address, cloudflare

I have an IP address 65.1.106.XXX. In this instance, Nginx is running and I can able to see the nginx status page through this IP address.

Now I'm trying to map the subdomain to this instance IP address.

I created **`test.conf`** file under the **`/etc/nginx/conf.d`**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name test.abc.com;


        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

and I'm trying to map this in Cloudflare and it has done.

but when I'm trying to access this subdomain it keeps below the error page

[image: Timed Out error]

Comment: How are your DNS records set up in Cloudflare?

Comment: yes, we do setup DNS records setup successfully. its working fine there

Comment: The question is how exactly the records are set up.

Comment: do you this sub domain (test.abc.com)